# Python re.split() misbehaving

Tags: python, regex, git

I'm trying to parse a log generated by `git log --numstat`.  It is in the format

```
commit 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Author: Joseph Shabadoo
Date: Sun Apr 21 14:34:36 2013 +0300

    fix the thing that was broken

4   0   foo.py
13  7   bar.py

commit aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd
Author: Donald Dont
Date: Fri Apr 19 21:15:00 2012 +0300

    do some stuff

15  6   foo.py

... etc
```

I have it stored in a file, and I want to split it into commits for easier parsing.  I am using `re.split()`, but can't seem to find the right regular expression for the job.  I would think using

```
re.split('.*?\n\n.*?\n\n.*?\n\n', myfile.read())
```

would work, but I got all of the first commit and the first two lines of the second commit lumped together as well (`commit aaaaa...` and `Author: ...`).  This is especially confusing, because there is not two successive newlines after the `Author:` line.  What regular expression can split this up?

EDIT: apparently `.` doesn't match the newline character by default.  The re needs to be compiled with the flag `re.DOTALL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just matching the first line, which is quite consistent?

```
'commit [0-9a-f]{40}'
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it would be nice to know why my regular expression isn't working.  It looks error-free to me, but...

Answer (score 3):

Let's visualize it:

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Your regex requires two newlines at the end of the match, and there is only one after the line

```
4   0   foo.py
```

Comment: Right, but there *are* two newlines after `bar.py`.  Why doesn't it terminate the match there?

Comment: @wiscocrew: Because the dot `.` doesn't match newlines unless you compile the regex using the `re.DOTALL` option.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks, haven't run into that before.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the lines, matching the line with `commit`. Then you can store all the lines with current commit in an array.

```
allCommits = []
currentCommitLines = []
for line in lines:
    if re.match(r'^commit [0-9a-f]{40}') and currentCommitLines:
        allCommits.append(currentCommitLines)
        currentCommitLines = []
     currentCommitLines.append(line)
```

Then you would have the commits stored in the array and you could parse/do whatever you'd like with them later.